# Mono: How to add a DLL reference in Makefile.am?

Tags: dll, mono, makefile, multiple-makefiles, autogen

I am trying to add a DLL to [CmisSync](http://cmissync.github.com), an [open source](https://github.com/nicolas-raoul/CmisSync) project that uses Mono and autogen/configure/Makefiles. It is my first time with Mono.

I copied the DLL to the relevant subdirectory, and modified this directory's `Makefile.am` at this line:

```
LINK = -r:$(DIR_BIN)/SparkleLib.dll
```

... I added the `DotCMIS.dll` like this:

```
LINK = -r:$(DIR_BIN)/SparkleLib.dll:DotCMIS.dll
```

Then I rebuilt the Makefiles at the root of the project:

```
./autogen.sh
./configure
```

Problem: Now I get an error when running `make`:

```
Making all in SparkleLib/Cmis
Makefile:545: *** multiple target patterns.  Stop.
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
```

It does not work with `-r:$(DIR_BIN)/SparkleLib.dll DotCMIS.dll` either.
I also try adding `LIBS=DotCMIS.dll` and `REFERENCES = DotCMIS.dll` line, no luck.

What is the correct syntax to add a DLL to a project that uses autogen/configure/Makefiles like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By trial-and-error I ended up making this lucky guess:

```
LINK = -r:$(DIR_BIN)/SparkleLib.dll -r:$(DIR_BIN)/DotCMIS.dll
```

Now that compiles fine!